# Rotating an image and saving it on client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-processing, client-side

Is there a way to rotate an image using jquery or javascript or any other client side library and the save that rotated image? I know there is a way to take that image to canvas, rotate it and then convert the final output into an image but is there any other way?

Comment: you can rotate using css3 which is more smoother compared to javascript type of rotations.
where do you wanna save by the way..

Comment: In one of the modules of my app, I want to check if the height of the image is greater than the width and then allow the user to edit it like zoom it and stuff. With css3 its just rotated for the display purpose ant not actually. Is there any js library like GD for php?

Comment: you can use combination of js and css3 for zooming also .you use css3 scaling for zoom. 

https://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/

Comment: jquery rotate doesn't actually rotate the image. It is just for the presentation.

Comment: check the documentation https://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Documentation we can even rotate

Comment: If you see here http://jsfiddle.net/xJnqM/1836/ the image is rotated on the presentation view but if you inspect the image you will see that the image isn't rotated actually.

Comment: Canvas is pretty much your way to go, because it allows you to read the rotated image data back – which a simple CSS rotation does not.

Comment: @CBroe that is what I am using right now but I was wondering if there is any other.